# Prevent MSTest to deploy to TestResult

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

When running all unit tests for a solution the .\TestResults folder get created in the same folder as the solution file (every time). I have tried to find out how to prevent this so the TestResults folder is not created at all and that all tests do run "in-place" instead.
So I don't want this TestResults folder to get created at all. It also takes a lot of disc space.

Things I have tried:
- Create a .runsettings file and selected that one in VS2017 (Tests --> Test settings --> Select Test Settings File). But it does not seem to use the file at all.
- Created a new project from scratch with a test project added. It works fine

//Regards Niklas